# Sorting a list of key-value-pairs according to preference facts?

Tags: sorting, prolog, predicate, swi-prolog

I have this list (read from a file):
[a-3,a-2,a-1,b-3,b-2,b-1,c-3,c-2,c-1,end_of_file]

Also i have the following predicates:

```
% ipo(A,B) -> A is preferred over B
ipo(end_of_file, _).
ipo(c-3,a-3).
ipo(c-3,b-3).
ipo(c-3,b-2).
ipo(a-2,c-3).
ipo(a-2,b-2).

% gr(A,B) -> A is better than B | for example a-2 is better than a-3
% for same key, the lower value is better
% also A is better than B if A is preferred over B

gr(X-I, X-J):- I<J.
gr(A, B):- ipo(A,B).

psort(>, E1, E2):- gr(E1, E2).
psort(<, E1, E2):- \+ gr(E1, E2).

rank(In, Out):-
    predsort(psort, In, Out).
```

The predicate rank(In, Out) uses psort as a predicate for predsort to sort my list for preference. Except it doesn't.

The input: rank([a-3,a-2,a-1,b-3,b-2,b-1,c-3,c-2,c-1,end_of_file], Sorted).

The actual output: Sorted = [a-3, a-2, a-1, b-3, b-2, b-1, c-3, c-2, c-1, end_of_file].

The expected output: Sorted = [a-3, b-3, b-2, b-1, c-3, a-2, a-1, c-2, c-1, end_of_file].

The output does not have to be unique. Important to the task at hand is the the preference facts are accounted for.

1. Is it feasible to do this in prolog?
2. What am i doing wrong?
3. What would be an efficient alternative to solving the task (like DAGs, Topological-Sort, ...) ?

**EDIT**

Using the helpful suggestions from CapelliC i managed to advance my program to the following:

```
ipo(c-3,a-3).
ipo(c-3,b-3).
ipo(c-3,b-2).
ipo(b-1,c-3).
ipo(a-2,c-3).
ipo(a-2,b-2).

gr(X-I, X-J):- !, I<J.
gr(A, B):- ipo(A,B).

psort(>, E1, E2):- gr(E1, E2).
psort(<, _E1, _E2).

rank(In, Out):-
    predsort(psort, In, Out).
```

The following test run, still shows erroneous output. That is 'b-2' should never be to the left of the 'b-3' because according to gr(2) b-2 is better than b-3.

```
?- combinations(L), append(L1, [_], L), rank(L1, Sorted).
L = [a-3, a-2, a-1, b-3, b-2, b-1, c-3, c-2, c-1, end_of_file],
L1 = [a-3, a-2, a-1, b-3, b-2, b-1, c-3, c-2, c-1],
Sorted = [a-3, b-2, c-3, a-2, a-1, b-3, b-1, c-2, c-1] .
```

Comment: (1) yes, (2) it's unclear - you show two actual outputs, but your code yields only one (apparently the correct one).

Comment: (2) you are correct - i mistyped. The second output, the correct one, is actually what i expect. I changed the 2nd 'actual' to 'expected'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About efficiency: I've changed your code to

```
gr(X-I, X-J):- !, I<J.
gr(A, B):- ipo(A,B).

psort(>, E1, E2):- gr(E1, E2).
psort(<, _E1, _E2).
```

(the cut means there is no point is examining the ipo/2 relation, when the same first element of pairs has been seen)

The outcome seems appropriate:

```
?- rank([c-3,a-2,a-3,a-1], Sorted).
Sorted = [a-3, c-3, a-2, a-1].
```

Of course, it's sorted from *lower* to *higher* preference. Just reverse it when done, or swap the operators in psort/3:

```
psort(<, E1, E2):- gr(E1, E2).
psort(>, _E1, _E2).

?- rank([c-3,a-2,a-3,a-1], Sorted).
Sorted = [a-1, a-2, c-3, a-3].
```

I would exclude `end_of_file` from the input list, and ipo/2 also, to clean up the specification. If it's not possible to correct the input 'routine', you could do

```
?- append(L, [_], [c-3,a-2,a-3,a-1,end_of_file]).
L = [c-3, a-2, a-3, a-1]
```

Last, ipo/2 seems incomplete (isn't c-3 preferred over a-1 ? I guess so...). A possible simple solution could be to left undefined the numeric field:

```
ipo(c-_, a-_).
...
```

Comment: Yes - ipo is not necessarily complete. The are gathered preference facts that are free from contradictions. The transitive closure is supposed to be accounted for by my predicate logic. The uncompleteness makes it possible for multiple valid solutions to exist side by side.